# After insert key does not appar in ef 4.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

SO I read here [In Entity Framework, getting the value of an identity column after inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306743/in-entity-framework-getting-the-value-of-an-identity-column-after-inserting)  that if you do this :

```
var entity = new Entity_Table { item1 = val1, item2 = val2 }; 
dbcontext.Entity_Tables.Add(entity); 
dbcontext.SaveChanges(); 
int newPK = entity.ID;
```

You can get the identity of the row you inserted. However, entity.ID does not appear in my sceneario.

```
My sceneario: 
1. I build the database with a sql script
2. Then I read it as a edmx file 
3. Then I ADO.NET DbContext Generator which creates NameOfMyEntity.Context.tt and NameOfMyEntity.tt
```

I can insert, update and delete successfully. But I cant see entity.ID. I receive no errors on runtime or compile time!@
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is no longer Entity.Id
is just Entity.Whateveryounameyourprimarykey

Comment: correct, in the article you read ID happened to be what they named their key. I highly recommend others don't use "ID" instead CustomerId, OrderId, etc even on the customer/order table itself.